# Rails Live: Dynamically send resut from method to browser

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, event-handling, dom-events

I am trying to notify the browser of the user of a change of the status of the model. I am trying to use the live-module of Rails for that. Here is what I have got so far:

```
require 'json'
class Admin::NotificationsController < ActionController::Base
  include ActionController::Live

  def index
    puts "sending message"
    videos = Video.all
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
    begin
      if(params[:id].present?)
        response.stream.write(sse({id: params[:id]},{event: "video_encoded"}))
       end
    rescue IOError

    ensure
      response.stream.close
    end
  end

  private
    def sse(object, options = {})
      (options.map{|k,v| "#{k}: #{v}" } << "data: #{JSON.dump object}").join("\n") + "\n\n"
    end
end
```

The idea behind the above controller is, that when its url gets called with a parameter, it would send this parameter (in this case the id) to the user. Here is how I am trying to call the controller:

```
notifications_path(id: video.id)
```

Unfortunately though, the following event-listener in the browser does not fire, even if I use curl to provoke an event:

```
 var source = new EventSource('/notifications');
 source.addEventListener("video_encoded", function(event) {
   console.log("message")
   console.log(event)
 });
```

The goal of this is, that I want to add an dom-element to a certain page (later on) if there is a change. There may be a better way, but Ruby Live seemed like a suitable solution. Any tips or proposals of a different approach are appreciated.

Comment: Your use case does not seem like a valid use case for `ActionController::Live`. You are not sending a streaming output to the browser. You do a one time check on ID and send the JSON output.

Comment: What would be a better way to handle it then?

Comment: Use a regular controller

Comment: But how would I inform the browser of the user about the change. I have a method that gets trigeered, if that methods gets triggered, I need to change something in the browser of the user, without reloading the page.

Comment: use AJAX and update the DOM on success callback.

Comment: But then I would need an interval and keep asking a method if something changed, no? I wanted to keep the number of requests as low as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case does not seem like a valid use case for `ActionController::Live`. You are not sending a streaming output to the browser. You do a one time check on ID and send the JSON output.

Use a regular controller and get the request by AJAX instead of EventSource.